# How to create logic in if else condition

Tags: c, if-statement

How to write the following condition using single if else?

```
int a;  //a can vary from 8 to 12
int b = 10;

a is equal to b
a is less than b by the margin of 2
a is greater than b by the margin of 2
```

In all above cases the if condition should be met. If margin is greater than 2, go to else condtion.

This Condition becomes true when value of a =7 or 13, which is not desirable

```
if((a == b) || (a <b-2) || (a > b-2))
```

Comment: How to do your homework yourself? What have you tried? Where is your code? What **specifically** don't work?

Comment: I am unable to satisfy above conditions in single if statement

Comment: The wording of the requirement is unclear. What does it mean "a is less than b by a margin of 2"? There are several possible interpretations of this. One is that `a = b-2`. Another interpretation is `a < b-2`. And yet another is `a <= b-2`.  Then comes the statement "if margin is greater than 2, go to the else condition'. that implies just the opposite - that the difference between a and b  is less than 3.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for here is to see that `a` and `b` differ by no more than 2.  You can do that as follows:

```
if (abs(a-b) <= 2)
```

This is true if the difference betwen `a` and `b` is less than or equal to 2.

If `a` is 8, 9, 10, 11, or 12, the above evaluates to true.  So this satisfies all the given conditions.

Comment: `stdlib.h` is not necessarily avaliable.

Answer (score 1):

Using the absolute value function `abs` in `stdlib.h`

```
if (abs(a-b) <= 2)
    do something;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

```
 if(a>=8 && a<=10)
  {
    if ( ( a == b ) || ( a + 2 == b ) || ( a - 2 == b ) )
     {
       // write your code here
     }
    else{
     //code of else part if above condition is not satisfied
    }

  }else{
    //if value of a is not in range i.e 8 to 10
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

a == b is not neccessary.

```
if ( !((a <= b+2) && (a >= b-2)) )  // False if "a" is between 8 and 12
```